# convert JSON from one key value pair to another

Tags: json, logic

I want to generate new JSON from the existing, but I am not able to do so.

Given JSON:

```
[
 {
   "id": "1",
   "firstName": "john",
   "lastName": "doe"
  },
 {
   "id": "2",
   "firstName": "michal",
   "lastName": "foo"
 },
 {
   "id": "3",
   "firstName": "john",
   "lastName": "smith"
 }  
]
```

want to convert it to:

```
[
 {
   "id": "1",
   "firstName": "john-doe"
  },
 {
   "id": "2",
   "firstName": "michal"
 },
 {
   "id": "3",
   "name": "john-smith"
 }  
]
```

I want only id name, but want lastName when only the firstName is same.
So, I am not able to do this condition of merging name, and add surname only when firstName is same

Answer (score 0):

Please try to mention the following in your question:

1. Technologies you are using
2. What you are trying to do/build
3. Code you have already tried to write
4. Errors (if any)